# Trouble obtaining quarterly values from a date variable in stata

Tags: datetime, stata

I am starting with a date_of_survey variable that is a string formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. I then run the following commands to convert it to a date variable, and display that variable in a useful format:

```
gen date = date(date_of_survey, "YMD")
gen date_clean = date
format date_clean %dM_d,_CY
drop date_of_survey
```

That leaves me with a "date_clean" variable displayed as "September 3, 2020" and a corresponding "date" variable displayed as "22161" (equal to days since January 1, 1960).

I now need to create a variable that indicates the year and quarter of each observation, preferably in YYYY-QQ format. I assumed this shouldn't be difficult, but no matter how I have coded it, I wind up with years in the 7000s and inaccurate quarters. I must be misunderstanding how the dates are stored. My first instinct was to try a simple `format date %tq` command, but I'm still not getting the output I need. Any help is much appreciated. I read over the help files, and can't find the discrepancy that's causing this little problem.

Comment: Cross-posted and answered, with more detail, at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1628218-trouble-obtaining-quarterly-values-from-a-date-variable  It's always a good idea to mention cross-posting.

Comment: 22161 is stored as an integer  in this case and all dates are stored as integers. You can control how it is interpreted with a display format. Changing the display format has no effect on what is stored. To convert to a different kind of date, you need a conversion function -- as you found. Much more in the link just cited and its reference.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: I needed to put the date variable into quarters since January 1, 2021.  a `qofd()` function call before the `format %tq` did the trick!